# Joda - Get the age from a birthday using a different format

Tags: android, json, jodatime

I'm learning how to build Android applications, and I'm trying to get the age from my users, only using the birthday.

I'm already using Joda timer, but I'm getting the data from a Json file, and this Json file outputs the data like this:

```
1994-11-24 / YYYY-MM-d
```

I'm getting the json data inside a for loop, in Java.

```
 //Variable

 private static final String TAG_BIRTH_DATE = "birth_date";
 ...

 //inside the Loop
 String birth_date = c.getString(TAG_BIRTH_DATE);
```

My question is, how can I format the date, and get the age from the person?

I tried this, so far.

```
                DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("d/MM/yyyy");
                LocalDate date = formatter.parseLocalDate(birth_date);

                LocalDate birthdate = new LocalDate (date);
                LocalDate now = new LocalDate();
                Years age = Years.yearsBetween(birthdate, now);
```

But is not working.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below method to calculate age of user and in parameter pass your date that you are getting from `JSON`

```
public static int getAge(String dateOfBirth) {

    Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar birthDate = Calendar.getInstance();

    int age = 0;

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
    Date convertedDate = new Date();
    try {
        convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(dateOfBirth);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    birthDate.setTime(convertedDate);
    if (birthDate.after(today)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can't be born in the future");
    }

    age = today.get(Calendar.YEAR) - birthDate.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    // If birth date is greater than todays date (after 2 days adjustment of
    // leap year) then decrement age one year
    if ((birthDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)
            - today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) > 3)
            || (birthDate.get(Calendar.MONTH) > today.get(Calendar.MONTH))) {
        age--;

        // If birth date and todays date are of same month and birth day of
        // month is greater than todays day of month then decrement age
    } else if ((birthDate.get(Calendar.MONTH) == today.get(Calendar.MONTH))
            && (birthDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) > today
                    .get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))) {
        age--;
    }

    return age;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have just mismatched your pattern and then accepted an answer which uses minutes instead of months (small "m" versus big "M). The **Joda-answer** would be (pay attention to the different pattern please):

```
String birth_date = c.getString(TAG_BIRTH_DATE); // example: 1994-11-24
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-d");
LocalDate date = formatter.parseLocalDate(birth_date);
Years age = Years.yearsBetween(date, LocalDate.now());
```